# Learning to refactor code: is there a short hand way of setting all buttons to have the same dimensions?

Tags: java, swing, button

I have just completed my first java program and now I am trying to refactor the code and make it more efficient/readable. I have a bunch of buttons that all share the same settings (except their location):

```
 JOneCarThree.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     JOneCarThree.setLocation(50, 210);  
     JOneCarThree.setOpaque(false);
     JOneCarThree.setContentAreaFilled(false);
     JOneCarThree.setBorderPainted(false);
    F.add(JOneCarThree);

    JOneCarFour.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     JOneCarFour.setLocation(10, 210);   
     JOneCarFour.setOpaque(false);
     JOneCarFour.setContentAreaFilled(false);
     JOneCarFour.setBorderPainted(false);
    F.add(JOneCarFour);

     JTwoCarOne.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     JTwoCarOne.setLocation(240, 130);   
     JTwoCarOne.setOpaque(false);
     JTwoCarOne.setContentAreaFilled(false);
     JTwoCarOne.setBorderPainted(false);
    F.add(JTwoCarOne);

    JTwoCarTwo.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     JTwoCarTwo.setLocation(240, 90);    
     JTwoCarTwo.setOpaque(false);
     JTwoCarTwo.setContentAreaFilled(false);
     JTwoCarTwo.setBorderPainted(false);
    F.add(JTwoCarTwo);

    JTwoCarThree.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     JTwoCarThree.setLocation(240, 50);  
     JTwoCarThree.setOpaque(false);
     JTwoCarThree.setContentAreaFilled(false);
     JTwoCarThree.setBorderPainted(false);
```

is there a way of setting these settings in one go? any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Note: variables and fields should have names that start with a lowercase letter. Only types (classes, interfaces) should start with an uppercase letter (of course, constant names should be all-caps including their first letter).

Comment: oops you are right! thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is just creating a method for each action you do separately to the buttons and then calling it on each one. Not the best but it it's 1 line instead of 6 for each button plus a method.

Answer (score 1):

First I would use a method which I call on every button:

```
void addButtonAt(Button b, int x, int y) {
     b.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
     b.setLocation(x, y);    
     b.setOpaque(false);
     b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
     b.setBorderPainted(false);
     F.add(b);
}
```

Then you can get more fancy by putting the buttons in an array and align them in the code:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[] {
    JOneCarThree,
    JOneCarFour,
    JTwoCarOne
}

for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
    addButtonAt(buttons[i], 100, 100 + i * 55);
}
```

Comment: Added that in and saved about 200 lines of code! thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this